# Put a table before title in rmarkdown pdf document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I would like to have a table above the title in the first page of my pdf report generated by `rmarkdown` :

[image]

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
date: '2023-01-03'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

I know in `Latex` one could use the following :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\title{test title }       
\author{testUser}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\maketitle
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

which then would do the trick, but in `rmarkdown` we do not use the `\maketitle` command !

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670474/put-a-table-before-title-in-rmarkdown-pdf-document

Answer (score 1):

If your tex distribution is reasonable up-to-date, you can use hooks:

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
date: '2023-01-03'
header-includes:
  - \AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/before}{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }\hline cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\  \hline \end{tabular}\end{center}\begingroup \let\newpage\relax}
  - \AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\endgroup}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

[image]

Comment: I'm getting error : 
`output file: test.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.101 \AddToHook
                {cmd/maketitle/before}{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c...

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted`

Comment: Ensure you latex installation is up to date.

Comment: @user9112767 As said in the answer, you need a somewhat recent installation. I think hooks were added around 2020. https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/07/22/latex-dev-2020-10-1b/

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, My os is Ubuntu 20.04, and the TexLive 2019 ! Is it possible to install new TexLive 2022 on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: @user9112767 You can install vanilla texlive from https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html instead of using these outdated linux packages

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I am behind the proxy and can not access `https://mirror.ctan.org/`, do you know if I could manually download the source file for linux and install it ? (I know how to download the iso image for windows but did not found similar file for linux)

Comment: @user9112767 The .iso from TUG should include all platforms, not just windows https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I have updated the texlive to 2022, now I'm getting the following error using your answer : `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: @user9112767 Can you add `keep_tex: true` to your header (like I just did in my answer) and then show the resulting .tex file?